# How can I remove the Theme owner and Powered by wordpress from my website?

Tags: php, wordpress, footer

I have tried everything to remove the 'Powered by Wordpress' and the Theme's owner's information. This is the footer.php file.. do I just have to delete it and update? and if so what do I delete?

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the footer.
 *

 * Contains the closing of the #content div and all content after

 *
 * @package base

 */
?>


</div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- wide contenitor-->
    <footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
         <div class="widget-footer container">
            <?php get_sidebar( 'footer' ); ?>
        </div><!-- .widget-footer -->
        <div class="site-info">
        <?php get_template_part( 'content/social' ); // Social link ?>        

        <?php esc_attr_e( '&copy;', 'base' ); ?> <?php _e( date( 'Y' ) ); ?> <a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url( '/' )) ?>" target="_blank" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>">
        <?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>
        </a>        
        <span class="sep"> | </span>         
        <?php printf( __( 'Theme: %1$s by %2$s ', 'base' ), 'Base WP', '<a href="http://themes.iografica.it" rel="designer">iografica.it</a>' ); ?>
        <span class="sep"> | </span>
        <?php printf( __( 'Powered by ', 'base' )); ?><a href="http://wordpress.org/" rel="generator">
        <?php printf( __( '%s', 'base' ), 'WordPress' ); ?></a>             
        </div><!-- .site-info -->
    </footer><!-- #colophon -->
</div><!-- #page -->

<?php wp_footer(); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be better to create a child theme, inheriting from your chosen theme, and then include your own footer file. This ensures that your changes will survive theme upgrades too. The Wordpress site has a page on how to do this - search for "Wordpress child theme".

Comment: Why does it bother you to give the creator of the theme credit for their work, or wordpress credit for making wordpess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried deleting this?

```
<?php printf( __( 'Powered by ', 'base' )); ?><a href="http://wordpress.org/" rel="generator">
<?php printf( __( '%s', 'base' ), 'WordPress' ); ?></a>
```

Comment: Assuming this is part of the theme, this will need to be done every time you upgrade the theme.

Comment: I will remember to do so!

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't remove the theme owners name as it can violate the license for the theme.

That being said remove lines 28, 30 and 31.

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the footer.
 *

 * Contains the closing of the #content div and all content after

 *
 * @package base

 */
?>


</div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- wide contenitor-->
    <footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
         <div class="widget-footer container">
            <?php get_sidebar( 'footer' ); ?>
        </div><!-- .widget-footer -->
        <div class="site-info">
        <?php get_template_part( 'content/social' ); // Social link ?>        

        <?php esc_attr_e( '&copy;', 'base' ); ?> <?php _e( date( 'Y' ) ); ?> <a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url( '/' )) ?>" target="_blank" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>">
        <?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>
        </a>        
        <span class="sep"> | </span>         
        <span class="sep"> | </span>
        </div><!-- .site-info -->
    </footer><!-- #colophon -->
</div><!-- #page -->

<?php wp_footer(); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "it can violate the license for the theme" - that depends what it is licensed under, I expect?

Comment: @Ian: read the whole sentence. It is in the form "You should not do X because doing so can Y". In other words, you must always do something because something may sometimes be true. That is, in my view, somewhat misleading - hence my comment.

Comment: @halfer Should !== Must. Should is simply advising.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to remove the credits? You can simply do it with one click by updating the theme to premium version. With the premium version you also have access to more advanced features and customizations.